# How does Aaron know where Marta lived in the Bourne Legacy?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-legacy

Aaron Cross (Jeremy Renner) arrives in the nick of time to save Marta Shearing (Rachel Weisz) when she is about to be killed by assassins, but how could Cross possibly have known where Marta lived?